# Is there any way to define the indivdual dataLabels connector width in a pie chart

Tags: css, highcharts, pie-chart

According to [Highcharts documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.connectorColor), it is possible to define the `connectorColor` from within the individual point properties.

I'm looking for a way to do the same but for the `connectorWidth` property because I want my connectors to have different width and styles based on the dataLabels they are connected to. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use the styled mode for Highcharts. See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/u4mhpg9o/

What I discovered is that if you apply a local style to the specific color assigned to your data label (or whichever custom style you create), you can change the connector width. In my example, I changed the width of the connector for pie slice #7 in the chart's stylesheet (avocados):

```
/* style defined in the demo for all connectors */
.highcharts-pie-series .highcharts-data-label-connector {
    stroke: silver;
    stroke-dasharray: 2, 2;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
/* local style just for connector #7 */
.highcharts-data-label-connector + .highcharts-color-7 {
    stroke-width: 20px;
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

You can figure out which style name is assigned to which pie slice by inspecting the code in your web browser.

Now, if you are **not** using styled mode, you can only change the connector width at the series level, not for individual data points.

I hope this information is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Actually, I'm trying to do this **not** using the styled mode.

The idea would be to have the connector width dynamically changed depending on the data that is passed to the pie. If that makes sense?

In the same way, somehow I can dynamically change the dataLabels and some connector properties depending on the data. 

Sorry if I was not clear on that particular aspect in my question.

Comment: @xuv I'm curious why you'd want to do that. What significance would changing the connector properties have on displaying the data to the user? How does that enhance or complement what you're already showing in the pie? My concern is that it would be too much "chart noise" for someone to understand. Without knowing anything else about your requirements, I'd advise that you consider different colors, a sliced pie (see the Chrome slice here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic), or a variable radius pie (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/variable-radius-pie).

Comment: I agree, it does not make much sense in this context. It's just that the design which I'm trying to implement using the highcharts pie component needs to display an extra data information (a Z axis data if you wish) and since Highcharts offers such flexibility to restyle and repurpose any of its elements, I was looking for a function like this. But I understand why it's not available. We resolved this by using the custom draw functions offered by Highcharts to add those custom lines to the graph.